# Group array with two words, rather than one

Tags: javascript, regex

CODE BELOW: When a word has been written, it stores that as its own array, meaning every single word is its own array, and then later checked for reoccurrences.

What i want: Instead of it creating an array of a word (after spacebar has been hit), i want it to do it after 2 words have been written.

IE: Instead of me writing "Hello" + spacebar, and the code creating "hello" as an array. I'd like it to wait until i've written "hello my" + spacebar and then create an array with those two numbers.

I am guessing this has something to do with the regular expression?
I've tried many different things (a little bit of a newbie) and i cannot understand how to get it to group 2 words together rather than one.

```
  const count = (text) => {

    const wordRegex = new RegExp(`([\\p{Alphabetic}\]+)`, 'gu');
    let result;
    const words = {};
    while ((result = wordRegex.exec(text)) !== null) {
      const word = result[0].toLowerCase();
      if (!words[word]) {
        words[word] = [];
      }
      words[word].push(result.index);
      words[word].push(result.index + word.length);
    }
    return words;
  };
```

Comment: Try `const wordRegex = /\p{Alphabetic}+(?:\s+\p{Alphabetic}+)?/gu;`

Comment: is it possible to turn that into a new RegExp object? as in the code later it uses a function from that object

Comment: `wordRegex` is a RegExp object here. You do not need a constructor here since it is a static pattern, it is not made of any variables.

Comment: I think it works! Could you please explain for me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
const wordRegex = /\p{Alphabetic}+(?:\s+\p{Alphabetic}+)?/gu;
```

**Details**

- `\p{Alphabetic}+` - 1+ alphabetic chars
- `(?:\s+\p{Alphabetic}+)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `\p{Alphabetic}+` - 1+ alphabetic chars

The second word is matched optionally so that the final odd word could be matched, too.

See the JS demo below:

```js
 const count = (text) => {

    const wordRegex = /\p{Alphabetic}+(?:\s+\p{Alphabetic}+)?/gu;
    let result;
    const words = {};
    while ((result = wordRegex.exec(text)) !== null) {
      const word = result[0].toLowerCase();
      if (!words[word]) {
        words[word] = [];
      }
      words[word].push(result.index);
      words[word].push(result.index + word.length);
    }
    return words;
  };
  
  console.log(count("abc def ghi"))
```

A RegExp constructor way of defining this regex is

```
const wordRegex = new RegExp("\\p{Alphabetic}+(?:\\s+\\p{Alphabetic}+)?", "gu");
```

However, since the pattern is static, no variables are used to build the pattern, you can use the regex literal notation as shown at the top of the answer.

Comment: One last question: Grouping the words in 3 instead of 2?

Comment: @CevinThomas Replace `?` (that is in fact equal to `{0,1}`) at the end with `{0,2}`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate it a lot!